# WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate Unlimited Nodes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate, xsd2code

I am having problems populating my treeview beyond the first level when the xml is using the same class name to have unlimited levels.  I have used Xsd2Code to create the object class.

To keep this post from being 3000 lines long, I am including a link for downloading the project.  It can be downloaded [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b1g13a3/n/MultipleLevelObject.zip)

My XML example

```
<Testing>
  <Numbers>
    <Number val="1">
      <Number val="1.1">
        <Number val="1.1.1">
          <Number val="1.1.2" />
          <Number val="1.1.3" />
          <Number val="1.1.4" />
        </Number>   
      </Number>
      <Number val="1.2" />
      <Number val="1.3" />
      <Number val="1.4" />
    </Number>
    <Number val="2" />
    <Number val="3" />
    <Number val="4" />
  </Numbers>
  <Numbers>
    <Number val="5" />
    <Number val="6" />
    <Number val="7" />
    <Number val="8" />
  </Numbers>
</Testing>
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:TestingXmlData x:Key="TestXML" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MainData" ItemsSource="{Binding Number1}"
                                  >
            <Border>
                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding val}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                </Label>
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding Number}"
                                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MainData}"
                                  DataType="{x:Type local:Number}"
                                  >
            <Border>
                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding val}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                </Label>
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </Grid.Resources>

    <telerik:RadTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestXML}, Path=TestingDataSource}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Test}"  
                         />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
public class TestingXmlData
{
    private Testing testing;

    public TestingXmlData()
    {
        this.TestingDataSource = new ObservableCollection<Number>();

        var t = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        testing = Testing.LoadFromFile(t + @"../../Test.xml");

        var numberBranch = (from tt in testing.Items
                   select tt.Number).ToList();

        foreach (var num in numberBranch)
            foreach (var entry in num)
                this.TestingDataSource.Add(entry);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Number> TestingDataSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a typo on your MainData Itemssource Binding to Number*1* ?

Comment: No it is not.  Since I am using the same node 'Number' for the inner node levels, Xsd2Code uses 'Number' for the outer level and 'Number1' for all inner levels.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already have solved this, but for me, DataTemplates (HierarchicalDataTemplate as well) never worked properly, if I had defined x:Key and DataType at the same time. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433802/why-should-we-use-datatemplate-datatype) asks about DataTemplates' DataType:

> This property that is very similar to the [TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) property of the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) class. When you set this property to the data type without specifying an **x:Key**, the [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) gets applied automatically to data objects of that type. Note that when you do that the **x:Key** is set implicitly. Therefore, if you assign this [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) an **x:Key** value, you are overriding the implicit **x:Key** and the [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) would not be applied automatically.

I ended up creating one DataTemplate with x:Key and second one with DataType, which had just one ContentControl that had ContentTemplate set to DataTemplate with x:Key.