# Why should we use DataTemplate.DataType

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

When I am creating a Resource we are specifying the DataType inside it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StudentView"
                  DataType="this:StudentData">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StudentFirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StudentGradePointAverage}"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
<Window.Resources>
```

And while binding :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheStudents}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudentView}">
```

So why are we using the DataType, even if I remove the DatType , my sample runs fine. Is it restricting certain types , that can be inside DataTemplete?

But I tried binding one of the TextBox with a garbage value (Not present in the View-Model) and it works fine!

Comment: One advantage is that knowing the expected data context type allows for some static verification of whether binding paths are valid.  It's also a documentation hint to future developers of the intention of the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 12):

The `DataType` is for implicit application, if you drop the `x:Key` you do not need to reference it in the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` for example. Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx).

> This property that is very similar to the [TargetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) property of the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) class. When you set this property to the data type without specifying an **x:Key**, the [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) gets applied automatically to data objects of that type. Note that when you do that the **x:Key** is set implicitly. Therefore, if you assign this [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) an **x:Key** value, you are overriding the implicit **x:Key** and the [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) would not be applied automatically.